# How to sort a HashMap in ascending order

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I have the following Key : Value pairs.

```
A56:A64=9, A65:A73=9, A2:A8=7, A49:A55=7, A20:A26=7, A9:A19=11, A43:A48=6, A27:A42=16
```

I want to sort them in an ascending order. I tried using a `TreeMap` but a got this :

```
{A20:A26=7, A27:A42=16, A2:A8=7, A43:A48=6, A49:A55=7, A56:A64=9, A65:A73=9, A9:A19=11}
```

A2:A8=7 should be first, but it is coming third.

Please let me know how I can fix this.

Comment: "ascending order" of what? Key, values?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: you can use Collections.sort with a comparator. so you can decide how it will compare

Comment: Default comparator sorts strings in *lexicographical* order. What you need is called *numerical order*. Check out the link in my previous comment if you want to implement custom comparator for hashmap

Comment: I want in ascending order of Keys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TreeMap` for a `String` key would use String lexicographical order by default (that's the natural ordering for `String`s), unless you supply your own Comparator in the constructor.

A2:A8 comes after A20:A26 when using lexicographical order.

Your comparator would probably have to split the String key into 4 parts (for example, `A20:A26` would be split to `A`, `20`, `A` and `26`) and compare each pair of parts separately, using integer comparison for the integer parts.

Comment: I splited the key on ":" then took the first parameter and replaced the "A", which gave me numeric value and normal TreeMap worked there.thanks